# R: Concatenate all entries by value in another column and add their counts

Tags: r, formatting

I have a dataframe dogs that looks like so:

```
dogid  home  school  month1year2014trainingtype1  month2year2014trainingtype1
12345  a     a       340                          360
12345  b     a       10                           0
31323  g     c       500                          550
41213  a     b       200                          400
41213  g     c       500                          100
41213  c     b       400                          20
```

Except that there are many more columns of counts (every combination of 12 months, 2 years, and 2 training types). Currently there is a separate row with separate counts for each unique combination of dogid, home and school. What I would like to do is combine all the counts for each dogid, and concatenate all the home and school values that ever go to that dogid (with no repeats).

So in the example above, I would like my table to look like:

```
dogid  home  school  month1year2014trainingtype1  month2year2014trainingtype1
12345  a|b   a       350                          360
31323  g     c       500                          550
41213  a|g|c b|c     1100                         520
```

So that there is one row for each dogid, the home column lists every home that has occurred for that dogid (but does not repeat eg. doesn't have b|c|b, instead has b|c), same for school, and then has the combined counts for each count column of all the rows that dogid initially had.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `dplyr` to get the summarized output.  We group by 'dogid', use `summarise` to `paste` the `unique` elements in 'home', 'school' separately, and do the `sum` for the column names that start with 'month'.

```
library(dplyr)
dogs %>% 
   group_by(dogid)%>%
   summarise(home = paste(unique(home), collapse='|'),
             school = paste(unique(school), collapse='|'),
             month1year2014trainingtype1 = sum(month1year2014trainingtype1),
             month2year2014trainingtype1 = sum(month2year2014trainingtype1))
```

gives the output

```
# dogid  home school month1year2014trainingtype1 month2year2014trainingtype1
#1 12345   a|b      a                         350                         360
#2 31323     g      c                         500                         550
#3 41213 a|g|c    b|c                        1100                         520
```

If we have multiple columns to `paste` the `unique` elements, also another set of columns to get the `sum`, we can do this with `summarise_each` separately, and then `cbind` the columns using `bind_cols`.  Here, I am using `matches` to select the column names that have only non-numeric strings from start to end.  But, this could also be done by subsetting the columns by checking the `class`.

```
dogs1 <- dogs %>%
           group_by(dogid)%>%
           summarise_each(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse='|')),matches('^\\D+$'))


dogs2 <- dogs %>%
           group_by(dogid)%>%
           summarise_each(funs(sum = sum(., na.rm=TRUE)), starts_with('month' ))

bind_cols(dogs1, dogs2[-1])
#  dogid  home school month1year2014trainingtype1 month2year2014trainingtype1
#1 12345   a|b      a                         350                         360
#2 31323     g      c                         500                         550
#3 41213 a|g|c    b|c                        1100                         520
```

#### data

```
dogs <- structure(list(dogid = c(12345L, 12345L, 31323L, 41213L, 41213L, 
41213L), home = c("a", "b", "g", "a", "g", "c"), school = c("a", 
"a", "c", "b", "c", "b"), month1year2014trainingtype1 = c(340L, 
10L, 500L, 200L, 500L, 400L), month2year2014trainingtype1 = c(360L, 
0L, 550L, 400L, 100L, 20L)), .Names = c("dogid", "home", "school", 
"month1year2014trainingtype1", "month2year2014trainingtype1"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do this less manually if I have 50+ columns of counts?

Comment: @user3051065 If you have multiple `paste` columns and count columns, do those separately with `summarise_each` and use `bind_cols`

Comment: @user3051065 Do you have all the count column names that start with `month`.  I updated the code.  If there is change in column names, you can change the `matches` or `starts_with`.